# brakes binding after sitting motorcycle

Tags: motorcycle, brakes, binding

If I leave my bike sitting for a few days it seems the brakes stick.

It is harder(not that hard) to push and can hear the drag more than normal.

What could cause this? After using the brakes it free's up fine with no issues.
Any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Are the brakes getting moisture on them?  If you get surface rust (even very light, hard to see), it will do exactly that.

Comment: Quite possibly, the weather is pretty crap at the minute. Thank you for a very good point! One caliper has new pistons but the other have the old pistons in still so that would be affected more. Would a good few blasts of brake cleaner up there help? Cheers

Comment: No, the reason this happens is the brake disc is bare steel, which, when exposed to moisture in the air, will rust. This is normal and happens with all steel disc brakes. In order to not rust, the bike would have to be kept in a climate controlled environment, where there is not enough moisture to cause rust.